# Facebook SDK returned an error: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, ssl-certificate

I am constantly getting this error on ubuntu while trying to generate Access token using facebook php-graph-sdk.

**Facebook SDK returned an error: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /var/www/html/fb/vendor/HttpClients/certs/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem CApath: /etc/ssl/certs**

while the same code works fine on windows environment.